# How to get proper types using nestjs TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am using nestjs and TypeORM to have my users created in the database. I already have 'entities' that work fine but this one is hard for me to resolve.

I am getting an error:

```
Type 'User[]' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, username, password ts(2739)
```

**user.entity.ts**:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: String;
}
```

**user.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private UserRepository: Repository<User>,
  ){}
  

  async find(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
     **return** this.UserRepository.find();
  }
```

This return is showing the error:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and **user.module.ts**:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Any help would be ore than welcome.

Thanks in advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpe7O.png

Answer (score 0):

`find` can return an array of users, depending on the `where` conditions, so Typescript is warning you of that. Either use `findOne` to include a `LIMIT 1` to the query, or filter out the results yourself and return `users[0]`